# NGINX Ingress Controller is crashing on

Tags: nginx-ingress

I am using AWS EKS service with Network LoadBalancer and I install ingress-nginx using helm chart now somehow I receiving logs like

[alert] 29#29: worker process 3106 exited on signal 11 (core dumped)

Does anyone have any idea what is the problem with this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l689P.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.